# How to unset limit of pods to Unlimited in Kubernetes Yaml fle?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, yaml

At first, I set limit range for namespace `kube-system` as below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: LimitRange
metadata:
  name: cpu-limit-range
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  limits:
  - default:
      cpu: 500m
      memory: 500Mi
    defaultRequest:
      cpu: 100m
      memory: 100Mi
    type: Container
```

However, later found that there is insufficient CPU and Memory to start up my pod as limits are > 100% from namespace `kube-system` already.

How can I reset reasonable limits for pods in `kube-system`. It is better to set their limits to `unlimitted` but I don't know how to set it.

---

Supplement information for namespace `kube-system`:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if your `kube-system` namespace has a limit set. You can confirm it checking the namespace itself:

```
kubectl describe namespace kube-system
```

If you have a limit range or a resource quota set, it will appear in the description. Something like the following:

```
Name:         default-cpu-example
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Active

No resource quota.

Resource Limits
 Type       Resource  Min  Max  Default Request  Default Limit  Max Limit/Request Ratio
 ----       --------  ---  ---  ---------------  -------------  -----------------------
 Container  cpu       -    -    500m             1              -
```

In this case I have set resource limits for my namespace.

Now I can list all the ResourceQuotas and LimitRanges using:

```
kubectl get resourcequotas -n kube-system
kubectl get limitranges -n kube-system
```

If somethings returns, from those you can simply remove it:

```
kubectl delete resourcequotas NAME_OF_YOUR_RESOURCE_QUOTA -n kube-system
kubectl delete limitranges NAME_OF_YOUR_LIMIT_RANGE -n kube-system
```

I'm still not sure if that's your true problem, but that answers your question.

You can find more info here:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/cpu-default-namespace/

Comment: hi @Juliano, thanks for your reply. I added node and namespace information for reference. You may see that I removed all Limit Ranges and recreate pods already, the Limits of them are still high which makes me cannot deploy my pods successfully.

Comment: In your case the problem is not the resource limit, is the size of your node. There is no resource limit set in the `kube-system` namespace.

Comment: But it is Azure B2s VM already which has 2 CPU and 4 GB. 
From the screen capture above, even I did nothing but kube-system used all resource already. 
Do you have any ways to set each deployment/pod with different limits?
As I tried to use `kubectl describe deployment xxx` then it show different requests and limits for different deployments. Thanks.