# How to change CPU Limit for namespace kube-system

Tags: azure, kubernetes, resources, cpu, limit

How to change CPU Limit for namespace `kube-system` in Azure Kubernetes? My pod could not be deployed successfully due to some pods from namespace `kube-system` using lots of resource.

[image]

Comment: Is it Azure AKS? If so, please find [very similar question and answer from microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/530768/coredns-high-cpu-limits-set.html). In short words, this is automated and any changes will be rewritten later.

Comment: hi All, just contacted MS support that we cannot change the limits form kube-system namespace. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting this as community wiki out of comment, feel free to edit and expand

---

In short words, this is not possible to change limits for `coreDNS` and other critical resources located within `kube-system` namespace. (Technically it's possible to set custom values, but they will be overwritten shortly and initial state will get back to pre-defined one, below answer from microsoft how exactly it works).

---

There's a very similar question to it on `microsoft question platform` and this is the answer:

> The deployment coredns runs system critical workload using the CoreDNS
> project for cluster DNS management and resolution with all 1.12.x and
> higher clusters. [Reference].
>
> If you do a kubectl describe deployment -n kube-system coredns, you
> will find a very interesting label
> addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode=Reconcile
>
> Now, addons with label addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode=Reconcile will
> be periodically reconciled. Direct manipulation to these addons
> through apiserver is discouraged because addon-manager will bring them
> back to the original state. In particular:
>
> - Addon will be re-created if it is deleted.
> - Addon will be reconfigured to the state given by the supplied fields
>   in the template file periodically.
> - Addon will be deleted when its manifest file is deleted from the
>   $ADDON_PATH.
>
> The $ADDON_PATH by default is set to /etc/kubernetes/addons/ on the
> control plane node(s).
>
> For more information please check this document.
>
> Since AKS is a managed Kubernetes Service you will not be able to
> access $ADDON_PATH. We strongly recommend against forcing changes to
> kube-system resources as these are critical for the proper functioning
> of the cluster.

Which was also confirmed in comment by OP:

> just contacted MS support that we cannot change the limits form
> kube-system namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the resource quota for the namespace

```
kubectl describe quota

kubectl get quota
```

> When several users or teams share a cluster with a fixed number of
> nodes, there is a concern that one team could use more than its fair
> share of resources.
>
> Resource quotas are a tool for administrators to address this concern.
>
> A resource quota, defined by a ResourceQuota object, provides
> constraints that limit aggregate resource consumption per namespace.
> It can limit the quantity of objects that can be created in a
> namespace by type, as well as the total amount of compute resources
> that may be consumed by resources in that namespace.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: List
items:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: ResourceQuota
  metadata:
    name: pods-high
  spec:
    hard:
      cpu: "1000"
      memory: 200Gi
      pods: "10"
    scopeSelector:
      matchExpressions:
      - operator : In
        scopeName: PriorityClass
        values: ["high"]
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/

i would also suggest checking the `LimitRange`

if **LimitRange** is supported into the cluster it might be assigning default resources to POD however editing `Resourcequote` will resolve your issue.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/memory-default-namespace/

Comment: Thanks @Harsh. Actually I tried to use LimitRange before in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69202328 but still cannot start my pod successfully even in 4CPU machine. Then I found out how to change the limits by using `kubectl edit deployment -n kube-system xxx` but it will go back original value after I changed another pod. Do you have any ideas? thanks.

Comment: Did you checked quota ?

Comment: Yes, I used `kubectl get quota --all-namespaces` with return `No resources found`.